# FileReference.save ensuring it has extension

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I need to save an XML with some settings and wanted to save them as my own filetype (.genconf for example). When i use..

```
var f:FileReference = new FileReference();
f.save( MyByteArray);
```

..I can allow the user to browse to save, but it only uses an extension if they enter in manually (which they definitely wont).

Is there a way to check the filename they enter, and amend/append it before the file is written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how i did it in the end (with AIR):

```
//on save clicked
public function export(e:MouseEvent){
    var file:File = File.desktopDirectory;
    file.browseForSave("Save");
    file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onSaveSelect);
}

public function onSaveSelect(e:Event){
    //create XML stuff here
    var config:XML = new XML(<config />)

    // compressing before saving
    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    bytes.writeUTFBytes( config );
    bytes.compress();

    //get browse location
    var saveFile:File = File(e.target);
    var directory:String = saveFile.url;

    //check if by miracle they put the extension in, then add it
    if(directory.indexOf(".genconf ") == -1){
        directory += ".genconf ";
    }

    //use the new path with the extension
    var file:File = new File();
    file = file.resolvePath(directory);

    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onClose);
    fileStream.openAsync(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    fileStream.writeBytes(bytes);
    fileStream.close();
}
```

Comment: I put my answer assuming that you need it for flash because with AIR we have certainly more options and flexibility ;)

Comment: yea, sorry about that I should have tagged it for AIR aswell. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

I think that for Flash security reason you can not force the file extension in any way, in addition the file name typed by user is a read-only information so you can not modify it.

So for your case, you want to save files with the `.genconf` extension, I think that you can :

- Request the file name to your user, before showing the save dialog, and then add the extension to have the default file name for the save dialog.

OR

- Fix the default file name with your extension using time-stamp, randomized name, ... and demand to your user to save the file directly without editing the name.

In all cases, you will get a code like this :

```
const extension:String = '.genconf';

var file_ref:FileReference = new FileReference()    
    file_ref.save('your_data', 'default_file_name' + extension);
```

Hope that can help.